# Need a wireless card for packet injection. On OSX

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, sniffing

I'll be doing a project for my wireless security course and I need a network card that can inject packets and do packet sniffing for my early 2009 macbook.

What is the recommended card for packet injection?  Obviously, preferably USB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use an Alfa 500mW 802.11b/g USB WiFI Adapter that I got on Amazon cheap. Seems to work fine.